# Where to save Keepass' file?

Tags: keepass

Using Keepass since a year ago, been told it's an excellent method to store one's passwords.

But what is the best location to save Keepass' file (the file where all password are stored and that you use when reinstalling Windows for example)?

Comment: I'm not sure that we can answer "best" for you.

Comment: You need to better describe your needs and security concerns before we can answer this. I can say that many people use a USB and/or Dropbox (and similar services) for storing their KeePass file. Keep in mind that the file is secured with strong encryption even if it is leaked to an attacker.

Comment: Haven't thought about the file's encryption, so most hackers won't be able to do anything of my file without the master password right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

- Save it on someone else's server (Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.) if you want convenience at the expense of security

  - And the first time you accidentally type your KeePass password into your Dropbox/Google Drive login, you just gave that someone else the keys to open up your password vault.
- Save it on your own machines, set up so they aren't backed up to someone else's server (i.e. the cloud), and sync the various KeePass files as you need.
- Save it on your own encrypted machines, on encrypted storage - perhaps LUKS (built into Linux) or [Veracrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/), or an [Apricorn FIPS 140-2 validated USB drive](http://www.apricorn.com/products/hardware-encrypted-drives.html), or a combination.
- Save it on your own guaranteed offline, isolated machine/storage

  - For more details on more secure - and less convenient - isolation, see [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/112737/39623)